# Kubernetes Control Plan - All kubectl commands fail with 403 Forbidden

Tags: kubernetes

OS: Redhat 7.9

Docker and Kubernetes (kubectl,kubelet,kubeadm) installed as per the documentation.
Kuberenetes cluster initialized using

```
sudo kubeadm init
```

After this all, on checking 'docker ps', find all the services up.

But all kubectl commands except for 'kubectl config view' fail with error
'**Unable to connect to the server: Forbidden**'

Comment: Run `kubectl config view -v=10 > /dev/null` and add the output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with corporate proxy. I had to set the 'no_proxy' as ENV variable and also as part of docker proxy and this issue got resolved.